# How to find the TypeLib for IDebugEngine2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, com-interop, atl

I want to make a .Net wrapper around the ATL COM based IDebugEngine2 interface, which is defined in msdbg.h in the namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop. Ultimately, I want to make a debugging engine in C#.

I am completely new to COM and ATL and I'm having a hard time with the "Implement Interface Wizard..." in Visual Studio 2010 in that I have no idea where to find the tlb for IDebugEngine2. I tried opening the dll but I get an error:

> No type library found in file ...\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.dll

How can I get the type library for this interface? Or perhaps there's a better way to go about all this, in which cast please do tell.

Comment: There is none, you import the IDL.  Avoid the wizard, follow [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb146253.aspx).

Comment: @Hans If you want to make your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I don't like duplicating content, this belongs in the MSDN library.

Answer (score 0):

The type library does not have/need to be public. It presumably exists (even its name is known to be [`LIBID_AD2Lib`](https://code.google.com/p/nbehave/source/browse/trunk/tools/vs2010.sdk/Inc/msdbg.h?r=17ca00c530403af14f5e81fd8d9d64d767822dbc)) and it is standing behind the public SDK header, however it does not require the type library to be present in system or distributed. I suppose that for whatever reason MS decided to not include it into public release.